# alsa: latency increases at every underrun

Tags: linux, alsa

I'm writing a tipical capture-process-playback loop. Capture using `snd_pcm_readi()`, some cheap audio process and then playback through `snd_pcm_writei()`. Single threaded.
At 128 period size and 96000KHz I cannot perceive any latency. Good.

Periodically I get a buffer underrun (`snd_pcm_writei()` returns -EPIPE); It's ok, I'm running a regular Ubuntu 16.04 desktop not configured for low audio latency.

After some underruns the latency becomes perceivable. I don't understand why.

this is my capture device configuration:

```
Plug PCM: Linear Integer <-> Linear Float conversion PCM (S32_LE)
Its setup is:
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : FLOAT_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 96000
  exact rate   : 96000 (96000/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 4096
  period_size  : 128
  period_time  : 1333
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 128
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 0
  stop_threshold   : 4096
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
```

And this is the playback device config:

```
Plug PCM: Linear Integer <-> Linear Float conversion PCM (S32_LE)
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : FLOAT_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 96000
  exact rate   : 96000 (96000/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 384
  period_size  : 128
  period_time  : 1333
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 128
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 384
  stop_threshold   : 384
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 6917529027641081856
```

when the underrun occurs I run `snd_pcm_recover()` and forget about the audio period that was just refused by `snd_pcm_writei()`. In my mind the next audio period will be played as soon I run `snd_pcm_writei()` and I will be again in a low-latency loop. But this is wrong, the latency increases.

No errors from the capture side of my loop.

What's happening? What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capture buffer is larger than the playback buffer. This is a good idea to reduce the risk of capture overruns (and you migth want to make it even larger, if supported by the hardware), but when the playback device stops for a short time, more data will have piled up in the capture buffer and does not go away faster than you can play it.

To ensure that the capture and playback devices do not lose synchronization, either

- stop both devices, and then start them again properly, or
- configure the playback device to disable underrun detection (set the stop threshold to the boundary value); this means that playback will just continue, even if there are no *valid* samples in the buffer, and your code then has to write samples until is has caught up. (With the default settings, the old samples in the ring buffer are played again during an underrun; if you've set the silence threshold/size to zero/boundary, silence is played instead.)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try both your solutions. But what I don't understand is why data piles up in the capture buffer; the audio period I wasn't able to play due to the underrun isn't anymore in the capture buffer just like any other data block I played correctly. As long as I can understand, playback and capture devices are completely separated, and from the capture point of view data blocks get pulled out at constant pace whether they get played or not. Where's my mistake?

Comment: As long as playback is stopped, you are not reading from the capture buffer either. If the playback and capture buffer had the same size, you would probably get xruns for both of them.

Comment: Does anyone know how to set the threshold to be boundary value with the 'aplay' command line tool? If I use the -T flag to set the stop_threshold to the boundary value it doesn't work. The stop_threshold gets set to a smaller value that what I input, and I still see increases in latency after underruns. Not understanding this behavior.

Comment: @ProjectileFish `aplay` does not have a parameter to set the stop threshold in samples.